# Attiny85 with arduino as ISP

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, isp

After serveral attempts, I can't make my arduino UNO to program an attiny85, no matter what I do. I've tried under windows 7 and also under ubuntu 14.04, to no avail. I've followed instructions on hi low tech site and similar ones on arduino site. Even some youtube video. Nothing. The wiring of my arduino is as described in those sites, so it should be correct. I'm using the 10uF capacitor too.

This is the output running avrdude manually, extra verbose:

```
    zop@mikasa:~$ sudo /usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude -C/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf  -q -pattiny85 -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b19200 -Uflash:w:/tmp/build2861466093518309047.tmp/Fade.cpp.hex:i -v -v -v -v -v -v -v -v  

    avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
             Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
             Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

             System wide configuration file is "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf"
             User configuration file is "/home/zop/.avrduderc"
             User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

             Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
             Using Programmer              : stk500v1
             Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
    avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
    avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
    avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
    avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
             AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
             Chip Erase delay              : 4500 us
             PAGEL                         : P00
             BS2                           : P00
             RESET disposition             : possible i/o
             RETRY pulse                   : SCK
             serial program mode           : yes
             parallel program mode         : yes
             Timeout                       : 200
             StabDelay                     : 100
             CmdexeDelay                   : 25
             SyncLoops                     : 32
             ByteDelay                     : 0
             PollIndex                     : 3
             PollValue                     : 0x53
             Memory Detail                 :

                                      Block Poll               Page                       Polled
               Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
               ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
               eeprom        65     6     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
                 Memory Ops:
                   Oeration     Inst Bit  Bit Type  Bitno  Value
                   -----------  --------  --------  -----  -----
                   READ               31     VALUE      7      1
                                      30     VALUE      6      0
                                      29     VALUE      5      1
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20    IGNORE      4      0
                                      19    IGNORE      3      0
                                      18    IGNORE      2      0
                                      17    IGNORE      1      0
                                      16   ADDRESS      8      0
                                      15   ADDRESS      7      0
                                      14   ADDRESS      6      0
                                      13   ADDRESS      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7    OUTPUT      7      0
                                       6    OUTPUT      6      0
                                       5    OUTPUT      5      0
                                       4    OUTPUT      4      0
                                       3    OUTPUT      3      0
                                       2    OUTPUT      2      0
                                       1    OUTPUT      1      0
                                       0    OUTPUT      0      0
                   WRITE              31     VALUE      7      1
                                      30     VALUE      6      1
                                      29     VALUE      5      0
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20    IGNORE      4      0
                                      19    IGNORE      3      0
                                      18    IGNORE      2      0
                                      17    IGNORE      1      0
                                      16   ADDRESS      8      0
                                      15   ADDRESS      7      0
                                      14   ADDRESS      6      0
                                      13   ADDRESS      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7     INPUT      7      0
                                       6     INPUT      6      0
                                       5     INPUT      5      0
                                       4     INPUT      4      0
                                       3     INPUT      3      0
                                       2     INPUT      2      0
                                       1     INPUT      1      0
                                       0     INPUT      0      0
                   LOADPAGE_LO        31     VALUE      7      1
                                      30     VALUE      6      1
                                      29     VALUE      5      0
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      1
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20     VALUE      4      0
                                      19     VALUE      3      0
                                      18     VALUE      2      0
                                      17     VALUE      1      0
                                      16     VALUE      0      0
                                      15     VALUE      7      0
                                      14     VALUE      6      0
                                      13     VALUE      5      0
                                      12     VALUE      4      0
                                      11     VALUE      3      0
                                      10     VALUE      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7     INPUT      7      0
                                       6     INPUT      6      0
                                       5     INPUT      5      0
                                       4     INPUT      4      0
                                       3     INPUT      3      0
                                       2     INPUT      2      0
                                       1     INPUT      1      0
                                       0     INPUT      0      0
                   WRITEPAGE          31     VALUE      7      1
                                      30     VALUE      6      1
                                      29     VALUE      5      0
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      1
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21    IGNORE      5      0
                                      20    IGNORE      4      0
                                      19    IGNORE      3      0
                                      18    IGNORE      2      0
                                      17    IGNORE      1      0
                                      16   ADDRESS      8      0
                                      15   ADDRESS      7      0
                                      14   ADDRESS      6      0
                                      13   ADDRESS      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9     VALUE      1      0
                                       8     VALUE      0      0
                                       7    IGNORE      7      0
                                       6    IGNORE      6      0
                                       5    IGNORE      5      0
                                       4    IGNORE      4      0
                                       3    IGNORE      3      0
                                       2    IGNORE      2      0
                                       1    IGNORE      1      0
                                       0    IGNORE      0      0
                                      Block Poll               Page                       Polled
               Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
               ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
               flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                 Memory Ops:
                   Oeration     Inst Bit  Bit Type  Bitno  Value
                   -----------  --------  --------  -----  -----
                   READ_LO            31     VALUE      7      0
                                      30     VALUE      6      0
                                      29     VALUE      5      1
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20     VALUE      4      0
                                      19   ADDRESS     11      0
                                      18   ADDRESS     10      0
                                      17   ADDRESS      9      0
                                      16   ADDRESS      8      0
                                      15   ADDRESS      7      0
                                      14   ADDRESS      6      0
                                      13   ADDRESS      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7    OUTPUT      7      0
                                       6    OUTPUT      6      0
                                       5    OUTPUT      5      0
                                       4    OUTPUT      4      0
                                       3    OUTPUT      3      0
                                       2    OUTPUT      2      0
                                       1    OUTPUT      1      0
                                       0    OUTPUT      0      0
                   READ_HI            31     VALUE      7      0
                                      30     VALUE      6      0
                                      29     VALUE      5      1
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      1
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20     VALUE      4      0
                                      19   ADDRESS     11      0
                                      18   ADDRESS     10      0
                                      17   ADDRESS      9      0
                                      16   ADDRESS      8      0
                                      15   ADDRESS      7      0
                                      14   ADDRESS      6      0
                                      13   ADDRESS      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7    OUTPUT      7      0
                                       6    OUTPUT      6      0
                                       5    OUTPUT      5      0
                                       4    OUTPUT      4      0
                                       3    OUTPUT      3      0
                                       2    OUTPUT      2      0
                                       1    OUTPUT      1      0
                                       0    OUTPUT      0      0
                   LOADPAGE_LO        31     VALUE      7      0
                                      30     VALUE      6      1
                                      29     VALUE      5      0
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20    IGNORE      4      0
                                      19    IGNORE      3      0
                                      18    IGNORE      2      0
                                      17    IGNORE      1      0
                                      16    IGNORE      0      0
                                      15    IGNORE      7      0
                                      14    IGNORE      6      0
                                      13    IGNORE      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7     INPUT      7      0
                                       6     INPUT      6      0
                                       5     INPUT      5      0
                                       4     INPUT      4      0
                                       3     INPUT      3      0
                                       2     INPUT      2      0
                                       1     INPUT      1      0
                                       0     INPUT      0      0
                   LOADPAGE_HI        31     VALUE      7      0
                                      30     VALUE      6      1
                                      29     VALUE      5      0
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      1
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20    IGNORE      4      0
                                      19    IGNORE      3      0
                                      18    IGNORE      2      0
                                      17    IGNORE      1      0
                                      16    IGNORE      0      0
                                      15    IGNORE      7      0
                                      14    IGNORE      6      0
                                      13    IGNORE      5      0
                                      12   ADDRESS      4      0
                                      11   ADDRESS      3      0
                                      10   ADDRESS      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7     INPUT      7      0
                                       6     INPUT      6      0
                                       5     INPUT      5      0
                                       4     INPUT      4      0
                                       3     INPUT      3      0
                                       2     INPUT      2      0
                                       1     INPUT      1      0
                                       0     INPUT      0      0
                   WRITEPAGE          31     VALUE      7      0
                                      30     VALUE      6      1
                                      29     VALUE      5      0
                                      28     VALUE      4      0
                                      27     VALUE      3      1
                                      26     VALUE      2      1
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20     VALUE      4      0
                                      19   ADDRESS     11      0
                                      18   ADDRESS     10      0
                                      17   ADDRESS      9      0
                                      16   ADDRESS      8      0
                                      15   ADDRESS      7      0
                                      14   ADDRESS      6      0
                                      13   ADDRESS      5      0
                                      12    IGNORE      4      0
                                      11    IGNORE      3      0
                                      10    IGNORE      2      0
                                       9    IGNORE      1      0
                                       8    IGNORE      0      0
                                       7    IGNORE      7      0
                                       6    IGNORE      6      0
                                       5    IGNORE      5      0
                                       4    IGNORE      4      0
                                       3    IGNORE      3      0
                                       2    IGNORE      2      0
                                       1    IGNORE      1      0
                                       0    IGNORE      0      0
                                      Block Poll               Page                       Polled
               Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
               ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
               signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                 Memory Ops:
                   Oeration     Inst Bit  Bit Type  Bitno  Value
                   -----------  --------  --------  -----  -----
                   READ               31     VALUE      7      0
                                      30     VALUE      6      0
                                      29     VALUE      5      1
                                      28     VALUE      4      1
                                      27     VALUE      3      0
                                      26     VALUE      2      0
                                      25     VALUE      1      0
                                      24     VALUE      0      0
                                      23     VALUE      7      0
                                      22     VALUE      6      0
                                      21     VALUE      5      0
                                      20    IGNORE      4      0
                                      19    IGNORE      3      0
                                      18    IGNORE      2      0
                                      17    IGNORE      1      0
                                      16    IGNORE      0      0
                                      15    IGNORE      7      0
                                      14    IGNORE      6      0
                                      13    IGNORE      5      0
                                      12    IGNORE      4      0
                                      11    IGNORE      3      0
                                      10    IGNORE      2      0
                                       9   ADDRESS      1      0
                                       8   ADDRESS      0      0
                                       7    OUTPUT      7      0
                                       6    OUTPUT      6      0
                                       5    OUTPUT      5      0
                                       4    OUTPUT      4      0
                                       3    OUTPUT      3      0
                                       2    OUTPUT      2      0
                                       1    OUTPUT      1      0
                                       0    OUTPUT      0      0
                                      Block


             Programmer Type : STK500
             Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [80]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [02] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [98]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
             Hardware Version: 2
             Firmware Version: 1.18
             Topcard         : Unknown
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [84]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [85]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [86]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [87]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [89]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
             Vtarget         : 0.0 V
             Varef           : 0.0 V
             Oscillator      : Off
             SCK period      : 0.1 us

    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [01] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [12] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: B [42] . [14] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [03] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [00] @ [40] . [02] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] . [00]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: PAGEL and BS2 signals not defined in the configuration file for part ATtiny85, using dummy values
    avrdude: Send: E [45] . [05] . [04] . [d7] . [a0] . [01]   [20] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
    avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
    avrdude: Send: P [50]   [20] 
    avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
zop@mikasa:~$
```

I don't know what else to try, so suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks.

PS: I had to strip out some of the output text because it was bigger than 30000 chars, I hope the info is good enough.

Comment: Some key information is missing; what board configuration did you target while uploading the sketch? High Low offers boards.txt with 3 different configurations, make sure to use the 1Mhz (ATtiny85 default). Also, please share your connections from the Arduino to the ATtiny

Comment: Try removing the capacitor, and add a wire between `5v` and `reset` on the UNO. You did upload the ArduinoISP example sketch right? (before adding the cap/wire)

Comment: @Gerben, the fact that the responses to the first number of requests to the programmer were received is pretty clear evidence that the arduino reset was not a problem and the right sketch was loaded.

Comment: avrdude has some weird error messages so I'm not confident enough to say that Send and Recv messages indicate it's working. But it might. Could you post a picture of your wiring? Or maybe the fuses are incorrect. Is it a brand new chip?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The wiring of the Attiny85 is correct. No misidentifications with pin 1 to 5: Dot mark is pin 1. The attiny85 are fresh as they came from the (local) store. The ISP sketch was loaded previously, then using the attiny 1Mhz for the board when trying to upload the blink example (changing pin 13, obviously). Using arduino as ISP as a programmer for the upload to the attiny's (tried 2 different chips). I have to say that I'm sure I'm using a CLONE, eventhough it says "arduino" all over and has the whitish color on the back of the PCB. I don't know if that could be the probl

Comment: I have had reliability problems with ArduinoISP until I reduced the baudrate to 9600.

Answer (score 3):

Your log demonstrates that

- Your programmer settings were correct.
- You have the right sketch loaded on the Arduino
- You have the Arduino auto-reset properly disabled.

The failure occurs at the point at which you're trying to enter programming mode. The two most likely error sources are:

- Your ATtiny85 is not wired up correctly (e.g. you misidentified pin 5 as pin 1, you used a wrong pin on the Arduino, you crossed two signals, etc).
- Your ATtiny85 is in a mode that prevents ISP reprogramming (programming the `RSTDIBL` fuse is the toughest of these mode, but merely setting the clock source to something odd will also cause this). Does your chip have a past, or is it fresh out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

I spent days with exactly the same problem (well, trying to program a 328p). Then I purchased a USBISP (aka USBICSP), and all my problems went away. I got one which had a "program slowly" jumper - setting this jumper will do the equivalent of -b19200, but without needing to explicitly set it, so you can do it from the Arduino IDE. Just my 2c worth.